# sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null); always returns success even when message not sent

Tags: android

I tried sms activity using [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/)
but the problem is that it always gives "message sent"
how to know if the message is really sent!

here is code

```
try {
  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mentioned link, there is no PendingIntent set for deliveryIntent or sentIntent in order to receive the status of message you need to send PendingIntent. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: I pass this  one PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar NPE scenario but problem at my end was due to wrong phone number.

So you must also check if **phone number** was correct or not.