# App crash because of strings?

Tags: android

my app loads up google maps and the user is drawing polylines in it... after he finishes the app sent his coordinates that he choose to another android device from his contacts list... now the problem is that when he draws more then 3 polylines when he is pressing the send button the app crashes and doesnt send an sms ... The app works up untill 3 polylines..
thats the logcat :

```
05-12 01:10:33.785: E/Gsm/SmsMessage(6255): hasUserDataHeader : false
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/43603 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.yeah/com.example.yeah.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:613)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:109)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at com.example.yeah.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:246)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
05-12 01:12:00.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6255):     ... 11 more
```

and thats the main :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    static boolean active = false;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       active = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       active = false;
    }
    public static boolean isActive(){
        return active;
    }



    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng>  points= new  ArrayList<LatLng>() ;
    Double glat;
    Double glon;


    //private final String UPDATE_MAP = "com.myco.myapp.UPDATE_MAP";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Enabling buildings of Google Map
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);


    googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
    Location lm = googleMap.getMyLocation();
    if (lm!=null){
    CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(lm.getLatitude(), lm.getLongitude()))
    .zoom(17)
    .build();     
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
    }
         }

    });






    // Setting OnClick event listener for the Google Map
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {


            // Instantiating the class MarkerOptions to plot marker on the map
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting latitude and longitude of the marker position
            markerOptions.position(point);

            // Setting titile of the infowindow of the marker
            markerOptions.title("Position");

            // Setting the content of the infowindow of the marker
            markerOptions.snippet("Latitude:"+point.latitude+","+"Longitude:"+point.longitude);

            // Instantiating the class PolylineOptions to plot polyline in the map
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Setting the color of the polyline
            polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

            // Setting the width of the polyline
            polylineOptions.width(6);

            // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList

            points.add(point);


            // Setting points of polyline
            polylineOptions.addAll(points);

            // Adding the polyline to the map
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            // Adding the marker to the map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);



        }
    });

    //Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
    //intent.putExtra("extra", fm); 
    //sendBroadcast(intent);


    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            // Clearing the markers and polylines in the google map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Empty the array list
            points.clear();

        }
    }); 


    if (points != null){
        Button pickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        pickContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);   


                      }
        });


        }

        else{
             Toast.makeText(this, "select points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, String.valueOf(points), null, null); 
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
        Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}



}
```

UPDATE:

thats before enerting to the line when i get null ... I draw 4 polylines= 5 coordinates

```
05-12 15:57:21.410: I/System.out(7375): 0523123345
05-12 15:57:21.410: I/System.out(7375): [lat/lng: (32.84536764138551,35.070853158831596), lat/lng: (32.84437612923071,35.07208328694105), lat/lng: (32.844574432547816,35.07010214030743), lat/lng: (32.84338460599924,35.071389600634575), lat/lng: (32.843805159677125,35.069672986865044)]
```

You can see that the first line is the number and the seconds line is the points... it seems ok so how come im getting null ther ????

Comment: `com.example.yeah.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:246)` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: yes ther's im sending the sms... maybe its too much strings inside the message body?? .... thats the line : " SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, String.valueOf(points), null, null);"

Comment: It seems that sentTextMessage is getting a NullPointer. Can you verify/print/debug the value of number and points ?

Comment: yes I updated it for you

Comment: maybe its String.valueOf(points)??

Comment: Hmm. Seems so. @mynavy use `System.out.println("val: "+String.valueOf(points));` and check if that's null. Else try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783476/sendtextmessagephonenumber-null-message-null-null-always-returns-success) solution.

Comment: I tryed it but its not a null ... With 2 polylines this line is not getting null with 3+ polylines it is... looks like its a bug or something

Comment: i meant that line : SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, String.valueOf(points), null, null);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i just found the answer ... : SmsManager.sendTextMessage() throws NullPointerException when SMS message is over size limit. i.e. max character limit is 159

very sad.

Comment: For all who come across this question .. thats the solution on how to send more then 160 char it works on real device only : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580675/how-to-send-the-sms-more-than-160-character